# Termine per uno che si atteggia

Tags: word-choice

C'è un termine per definire uno che si atteggia ad essere quello che non è nella realtà, in particolare uno che si atteggia come una persona ricca o benestante senza esserlo (e si vorrebbe esserlo)?

Comment: Non proprio esatto al 100%, ma una possibilità è *snob*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Di termini per definire chi mente o chi esagera la realtà ce ne sono diversi, alcuni con significati particolari, ma che possono essere usati anche nel tuo caso come:

> **Gradasso**: Chi si vanta di imprese e abilità inesistenti
>
> **Spaccone**: Chi si vanta di aver fatto o di essere capace di fare cose
>   inverosimili
>
> **Sbruffone**: Chi racconta fandonie o fa vanterie esagerate
>
> **Fanfarone:** Chi si vanta di aver compiuto o di poter compiere grandi imprese di
>   cui non è realmente capace

Il termine forse più corretto potrebbe essere millantatore.

> **Millantare**: Vantare con molta esagerazione: millantare le proprie ricchezze

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/millantare/

Comment: ***Millantare***, ottimo suggerimento, ma più nel significato  di *vantare cose non vere o comunque esagerate*, es: millantare importanti amicizie.

Comment: @Josh61 sì anche questo termine è generico, però può essere utilizzato anche quando si parla di ricchezza (almeno secondo la Treccani).

Answer (score 3):

[**finto**](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/F/finto.shtml)

> • agg.
>
> 1 Che finge, inganna; (anteposto al s.) che vuole apparire diverso da ciò che è: *fare il f. tonto*
>
> • s.m.
>
> 1  Dissimulatore, impostore

Uno che cerca di imitare il modo di fare e di atteggiarsi come un uomo ricco fino ad assumere la propria identità, come [Tom Ripley](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il_talento_di_Mr._Ripley), sarebbe un *[impostore](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impostore_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)* (letteralmente: chi fa credere cose non vere).

Answer (score 2):

Delle varie opzioni che mi vengono in mente quella che preferisco in questo caso è **impostore**:

http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=impostore

> **impostore** [im-po-stó-re] n.m.
>
> Chi falsifica o deforma la verità, approfittando della credulità altrui, 
>     per trarne vantaggio

ma credo che la scelta della parola specifica dipenda anche dalla sfumatura che si vuole dare nella frase.